# Searching a column name with its value='xyz' across a database in oracle9i?

Tags: plsql, oracle9i

we use a tool that operates on a certain database updating certain values when we makes some changes to the tool.
This takes a long time for some simple task.
I just need to find out which table,column and the value for that column gets updated.

for this i need to find out the whole database which column_name has value "XYZ" and the corresponding table/tables.

Any scripts for these.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Search all tables all columns for string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389666/oracle-search-all-tables-all-columns-for-string)

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5350405/330315

Comment: Another approach would be to trace the database while the tool is running.

Comment: Why is it that every time this question gets asked I have an overwhelming urge to run out the door, tearing my hair out and screaming "AIIIEEEE!!!!  CTHULHU!  CTHULHU FTHAGN!!!"?  Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Just because something *can* be done does not mean it *should* be done.

I know you've got your process designed this way and you very likely don't want to change it but, really, your life will get a whole lot better if you redesign this to avoid doing something that really, seriously, shouldn't be done.  Searching through every text field in an entire database in search of some magical character string is a Bad Idea.  It's actually only ONE of The Big Bad Ideas and it probably isn't the Baddest Idea, but it's a big enough bad enough idea that you should give Serious Consideration to doing something else, better.

OK, so what's wrong with it?

First, it indicates that you're not using a database, you're using a midden.  You dump stuff in and then hope to dig it out later.  This is the kind of thing people did thousands of years ago (it was popular back when flint was cutting edge technology), and while it helps keep archaeologists employed digging through these trash heaps, we are software developers, not archaeologists, and we don't want to have to do this kind of thing on a regular basis.

Second, this is a serious performance killer.  You're going to either write some god-awful static code to laboriously check every field in every table, or you're going to write some middling-bright code to dynamically create some even more god-awful query that will laboriously check every field in every table.  The word to focus on here is "laborious".  And "god-awful", if it comes to that.  Scanning through every row in every table in your database and testing every field in all of those every rows is going to be slow.  Very, very slow.  It's going to be dead-turtle-on-the-side-of-the-road-with-tire-marks-on-its-shell slow.  This is not a good thing to do, unless you own stock in the local electric utility and want to make sure every generated electron has a happy home in your employers computer.

Third, people will have strong emotions when they see your code.  Those destined for careers in management will laugh, for they know that *they* won't have to maintain it or try to solve the performance issues.  The technically challenged will cry, because they'll know there's nothing they can do to fix it.  The true Code Warriors will stare in amazement for a moment, and will then grit their teeth, hunt you down, and beat you to death with their ceremonial Wands Of Green-Bar, for only they will know that this evil could have been prevented.

So give some thought to a re-design.  Once again, just because something *can* be done does not mean it *should* be done.

Share and enjoy.