# Need Column name where I know the database and table names

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I know the database and table name and need to find a column name. Example as in `emp` table; I know data 7369 and table name as `emp`, and I need to get the column name as `empno`. My table has hundreds of columns and it is getting difficult to search each column name.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish? This might help someone help you.

Comment: You could adapt one of the answers from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/208493/266304) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6389666/266304) (or many others you could search for) to only look at a specific table. Also, by 'database' do you really mean 'schema'?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any choice but to search in every column. Please note though that this value could, potentially, appear in multiple columns and/or multiple times in a single column. There's no way to restrict how often it appears across an entire table.

This is the point of a database; everything stored in a column and, most importantly, that column has *meaning*. If you disassociate the data stored in a column from a meaning then you will have to search everything.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps, not using cursors or complex pl/sql, only SQL Plus.

1. Produce your search queries:

   select  select '||
          COLUMN_NAME || 
          ',count(*) from emp where ' || 
          column_name || ' = 7369 group by '||
          COLUMN_NAME || ';'
   from cols 
   where table_name = 'EMP';

EG:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select SECOND,count(*) from TESTER where SECOND = 7369 group by SECOND;
```

(in my env, Second was a column in table TESTER)

Capture the output, clean up the headers and the like, and run it.

It will return every column that matches, along with a count of how many rows matched.