# Search Table for a matching string Oracle

Tags: oracle

how can I search for a matching string in all columns of a table and its child tables which has foriegn key relationship and return the result.

Please someone, give me the oracle query for this.

Regards

Comment: how a tables are defined as 'child'? What is the idea behind this?

Comment: updated my question..please check

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Search all tables all columns for string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389666/oracle-search-all-tables-all-columns-for-string)

Comment: This is for whole schema...and this might choke the DB server. I want it for one particular table and its dependant tables.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 'select * from ' || table_name || ' where ' || clause
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(stragg(column_name)
                                  over(PARTITION BY table_name ORDER BY table_name), ',',
                                  ' = ''__your_string__'' OR ') || ' = __your_string__' clause,
                         table_name
           FROM user_tab_columns
          WHERE table_name IN
                (SELECT table_name
                   FROM all_constraints
                  WHERE constraint_type = 'R'
                    AND r_constraint_name IN (SELECT constraint_name
                                                FROM all_constraints
                                               WHERE constraint_type IN ('P', 'U')
                                                 AND table_name = '__yout_table__')));
```

Additionally you have to wrap it in a PLSQL or to loop in someway to execute each row of the record set.

Comment: ORA-00904: "STRAGG": invalid identifier ...i am facing this with your query

Comment: I tried using sys.stragg and it worked but still no results are fetched.

Comment: Did you replace __your_table__ with desired table name and __your_string__ with sought string? Which version of Oracle do you use?

Comment: I replaced as per your instruction but it dint work. Using oracle 11g

Comment: your recordset is empty or you receive any error? Try executing select statements one by one. If recordset is empty this should mean that perhaps __your_table__ has not foreign keys...