# Looking for tables/columns that contain specific substring

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way to query an entire Oracle database using sql or plsql to return a list of all tables/columns that contain the specific substring? Note that I want to look for the substring within the data (not within the table/column names themselves).

I have an issue where a character looks like a space, but is actually a different character.  I have proven this out by taking the substring text and putting it through a hexadecimal converter.  I need to be able to locate everywhere in the database this character exists, so I can replace it with an actual space.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use ALL_TAB_COLUMNS to search in column and tables using like

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Search all tables all columns for string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389666/oracle-search-all-tables-all-columns-for-string)

Comment: Thanks Gerrat, that gave me what I was looking for, and can fix my customers data appropriately now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for table and column names, you can use the view: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name LIKE UPPER('%search_string%') 
OR column_name LIKE UPPER('%search_string%');
```

If you want to search additional places for names, you could use the ALL_OBJECTS view:

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type 
FROM all_objects WHERE object_name LIKE UPPER('%search_string%') ;
```

Comment: ALL_TAB_COLUMNS will give me table and column names, but I need to be able to look for a specific substring within the data held in the columns, and then have a list of all the table/column names that have data stored in them that contain the specific character

Comment: ...so you want to go though every column in every table that has character like data and search for a string?  You need to write a stored procedure.  Grab table and column names from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, and compose a dynamic sql statement that searches each string-like column for your search string.  Have Fun.

Comment: I edited the OP to clarify that the request is to search data rather than column names as originally stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` table to search in column and tables using like.