# SQL Server: Search all tables for all rows with a specific value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

(I've seen a couple of other posts about this on StackOverflow -- specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389666/oracle-search-all-tables-all-columns-for-string/6389779#6389779) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995622/search-all-columns-all-tables-for-a-specific-value), but they both seem to be Oracle-specific, and I'm using SQL Server.)

So I've used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name) to get all tables that have a specific column.  That part works great, and it returns me over 100 tables.  This is what I'm using, from that post:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE 'myColumn'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

What I'm now looking for is a modification to that -- is there a way to get all of the rows in each of those tables where my target column name has a specific value?  Basically, I want to be able to rip through every table in the system and select every row where a specific column name has a specific value.  (I'll be trying to delete all those rows later, but `SELECT` first, `DELETE` later.)

Something along the lines of this (which I know doesn't work; it's for illustration purposes):

```
SELECT [row]
    FROM sys.tables tab
    JOIN sys.columns col ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
    WHERE col.name LIKE 'myColumn' AND col.value = 'myVal'
```

The only other option I can think of is to take the output from the first query and run a `SELECT` on each one, which would give me unwieldy output in SQL Server Management Studio, to say the least.

Is there a simple way to go about this, without resorting to external tools or whatnot?

Answer (score 3):

Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA catalogs.

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SOME_TEXT%'
ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/JPEZN41582

Comment: The problem is, I can already get all the tables that have the column in it.  I need all the rows that have a specific value in all the tables that have the column in it.

Comment: Then you need a dynamic query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/591991/3270427

Answer (score 2):

below is what i used to find all tables containing specific value for a specific column name

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(250);
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(250);
DECLARE @SearchValue varchar(250) = 'MyValue';
DECLARE @SearchColumn varchar(250)  = '%MyColumnName%';
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500);

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
TableName varchar(250),
ColumnName varchar(250),
)

DECLARE CUR_TEST CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT     t.name AS 'TableName', c.name as col_name
    FROM        sys.columns c
    JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE       c.name LIKE @SearchColumn
    ORDER BY    TableName;

OPEN CUR_TEST
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_TEST INTO @TableName, @ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into #TempTable(TableName, ColumnName) 
    select DISTINCT ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @ColumnName + ''' from ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = ''' + @SearchValue + ''''

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery

   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_TEST INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
END
CLOSE CUR_TEST
DEALLOCATE CUR_TEST
GO

select * from #TempTable
Drop Table #TempTable
```